# How get all defined routes from ReactRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I define my routes like this:

```
window.myRoutes = ReactDOM.render((
    <ReactRouter.Router history={ReactRouter.browserHistory}>

        <ReactRouter.Route  path="/" component={Home}>
            <ReactRouter.IndexRoute
                component={Main}
            />
            <ReactRouter.Route
                    path="/subpath"
                    component={SubPath}
            />
            <ReactRouter.Route
                    path="/subpath2"
                    component={SubPath2}
            />
        </ReactRouter.Route>
    </ReactRouter.Router>
), document.getElementById( "main" ) );
```

But when I try to access that in another component's `componentDidMount()`, it's undefined:

```
componentDidMount() { console.log( window.myRoutes ); }
```

How do I get all the routes defined?

**NOTE: I do not just want the routes in `this.props.routes` as that's just all the routes leading to the current one**

Comment: Why do you need to define your routes like that? because it looks very hackish way doing things. And also may not work on a server side.

Comment: @Shota How should I be defining them?

Comment: Here is some example for it: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/query-params/app.js . Also for getting all the routes check withRouter high order component: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options . It injects a lot of infos and functions of routing into your component. As far as I remember, it should also contain all the defined routes. Just make sure you have at least 3.0 version of react-router.

Comment: @Shota The example you posted defines them exactly the way i do. They're in a render call too!

Comment: What I wanted to say is that, you assigned your routes to the global variable. Most probably you don't need to do it. Did you try wrapping your component into withRouter HOC?

Answer (score 0):

With React Router v2/3, the `<Route>` components don't actually render anything. They are just converted to an object which the `<Router>` uses to match against the current location's pathname. If you want to have an object containing all of your routes, it is easy enough to define them as an object.

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route  path="/" component={Home}>
    <IndexRoute component={Main} />
    <Route path="/subpath" component={SubPath} />
    <Route path="/subpath2" component={SubPath2} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

is equivalent to

```
var routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: Home,
  indexRoute: {component: Main}
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'subpath',
      component: Subpath
    },
    {
      path: 'subpath2',
      component: Subpath2
    }
  ]
}
<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
```